# change colors of a scatter plot with double y axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've searched around, but have not found a solution. My goal is to plot a scatter plot with 3 sets of data, each set with a different color. Here is an example of my code:

```
%generate input
x1=[732490 732509 732512 732513 732521 732528];
y1=[7.828 7.609 22.422 14.758 26.258 1.477];
x2=[732402 732403 732404 732404 732433 732555];
y2=[0.693 0.645 0.668 0.669 0.668 0.662];
x3=[832402 832403 832404 832404 832433 835423];
y3=[0.693 0.645 0.668 0.669 0.668 0.685];
figure(1); 
[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(x1,y1,[x2,x3],[y2,y3],'scatter');
blue=[0 0 1];
red=[1 0 0];
set(h1,'cdata',red);
set(h2,'cdata',blue);
set(ax(1),'ycolor','r');
set(ax(2),'ycolor','b');
```

However, this is what exactly what I want, as [x2 y2] [x3 y3] has the same color. Is there a way to change the colors so that the three set of data has different colors? And also how to add a legend showing the three sets of data?

Comment: Could you please correct any mistakes in the code, it isn't working as posted. It says Error in plotyy>fevalfun (line 361)

Comment: Sorry, it is now updated and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overcome the limitation of `plotyy` by building your own plotyy by:

- create a `figure`
- add an `axes`
- add a second `axes` and:

  - make its `position` equal to th eone of the first axes
  - make it transparent by setting its `color` to `none"

Now you can select the axes on which to use `scatter` by specifying it as a first argument (e. g. `scatter(axes_1, ...)`).

After having plot all the data set, you have to make the `xlim` of the two axes equals.

To add the legend, you just have to specify the `handles" returned by the`scatter`function as first argument of the`legend` function.

This approach has been implemented in the following code.

In the code a check is made in order to verify if it is possible to use the *[dot notation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html)* (introduced in R2014b).

```
x1=[732490 732509 732512 732513 732521 732528];
y1=[7.828 7.609 22.422 14.758 26.258 1.477];
x2=[732402 732403 732404 732404 732433 732555];
y2=[0.693 0.645 0.668 0.669 0.668 0.662];
x3=[832402 832403 832404 832404 832433 835423];
y3=[0.693 0.645 0.668 0.669 0.668 0.685];
% Check if the "dot notation" can be used
dot_notation=~verLessThan('matlab','8.4')
%
figure
% Add the first axes
ax1=axes
% Add the second axes
ax2=axes
% Plot the scatter of the first set of data on the first axes
h1=scatter(ax1,x1,y1,'r','filled')
% Plot the scatter of the second set of data on the second axes
h2=scatter(ax2,x2,y2,'b','filled')
hold on
% Plot the scatter of the third set of data on the second axes
h3=scatter(ax2,x3,y3,'g','filled')
if(dot_notation)
   % Superimpose the second axes over the first ome
   ax2.Position=ax1.Position
   % Make it transparent
   ax2.Color='none'
   % Move the YAxis to the right
   ax2.YAxisLocation='right'
   % Adjust the X limits
   x_lim=[min([ax1.XLim ax2.XLim]) max([ax1.XLim ax2.XLim])]
   ax1.XLim=x_lim
   ax2.XLim=x_lim
   % Remove XAxis Tick
   ax2.XTick=[]
else
   ax1_pos=get(ax1,'position');
   % Superimpose the second axes over the first ome
   set(ax2,'Position',ax1_pos)
   % Make it transparent
   set(ax2,'color','none')
   % Move the YAxis to the right
   set(ax2,'YAxisLocation','right')
   % Adjust the X limits
   ax1_x_lim=get(ax1,'xLim');
   ax2_x_lim=get(ax2,'xLim');
   x_lim=[min([ax1_x_lim ax2_x_lim]) max([ax1_x_lim ax2_x_lim])]
   set(ax1,'XLim',x_lim)
   set(ax2,'XLim',x_lim)
end
% Add the legend
[a,b,c,d]=legend(ax2,[h1,h2,h3],'1° data set','2° Data set','3° Data set')
if(dot_notation)
   a.Color='none'
else
   set(a,'color','w')
end
grid(ax1,'on')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. I am able to apply this approach to my large dataset, and it works as intended. The only thing I changed is to add the second axes after having plotted the first one.

Answer (score 1):

In this example from matlab it is done without the scatter:

```
x = linspace(0,10);
y1 = 200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);
y2 = 0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);
y3 = 0.2*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);

figure
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(x,y1,[x',x'],[y2',y3']);
```

notice that if instead you write `[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(x,y1,[x,x],[y2,y3]);` you'll loose the third color, so you need the `[x',x']` instead of the `[x,x]`

I just tested your code but with `[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(x1,y1,[x2',x3'],[y2',y3']);` and I could see the 3 colors. Sadly when I do `[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(x1,y1,[x2',x3'],[y2',y3'],'scatter');` I keep getting the same

```
Error using scatter (line 44)
X and Y must be vectors of the same length
```

, even when I tried on the code from the matlab example. Apparently the scatter property does not allow you to have 3 set of data. If you check line 42 of scatter.m you'll see

```
[~, cax, args] = parseplotapi(varargin{:},'-mfilename',mfilename);
```

When you execute `[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2,'scatter');` which is only a 2 set plot you'll see how args in line 42 is a 1x2 cell with two vectors, yet when you execute `[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(x1,y1,[x2',x3'],[y2',y3'],'scatter');` which would be the only way of getting 3 colors

(remember `[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(x1,y1,[x2,x3],[y2,y3],'scatter')` will only give you 2 colors although it works within scatter.m as in args that is also interpreted as 2 vectors)

as now args in line 42 is a 1x2 cell with two matrices instead of two vectors that yields to a mistake.

Moreover using:

```
blue=[0 0 1];
red=[1 0 0];
set(h1,'cdata',red);
set(h2,'cdata',blue);
set(ax(1),'ycolor','r');
set(ax(2),'ycolor','b');
```

Isn't helpful as you can only manipulate 2 instead of three independent axis. So I guess that the answer to your question is NO IT CAN'T BE DONE (Although if you remove the scatter constraint it will).

Comment: Thank you for helping debugging. I marked it as useful, although I did not accept it as answer.

Comment: It is ok I am glad you could finally make it